# THREE ROWS LEAD FUNCTION IN ORACLE PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

My Table:

```
ID  NAME
1   SIVA
2   RAJA
3   PYTHON
4   SQL
5   ODI
```

I need to lead by 3 rows.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT LEAD(NAME,3) OVER (ORDER by NAME) as NAME FROM TEST_TABLE where NAME='SIVA'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
--------
| NAME |
--------
| SQL  |
--------
```

Example:

If I pass value as SIVA, then I need to get SQL as output.

Similarly if I pass value as Raja, then I need to get ODI as output

Is there any query to get the expected output?

Comment: I got null as ouput

Comment: `where NAME='SIVA'` will select exactly one row (given your sample data). How do you expect to get some value 3 rows "further down" if your result only contains a single row.

Comment: check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f32fd/3

Comment: Seems like your first try was nearly correct, perhaps you just want OVER (ORDER BY id)? (Edit: Note though you would have to evaluate the analytic function in a view and apply the WHERE clause afterwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be one option: it uses `row_number` analytic function which calculates *row numbers* so that you wouldn't have to rely on ID values. What if they are acquired by a sequence? It is not gapless. Basically - it is used for *safety*.

```
SQL> WITH test (id, name)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'siva' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 2, 'raja' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 3, 'python' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 4, 'sql' FROM DUAL
  9           UNION ALL
 10           SELECT 5, 'odi' FROM DUAL),
 11       temp AS (SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM test)
 12  SELECT b.name
 13    FROM temp a JOIN temp b ON b.rn = a.rn + 3
 14   WHERE a.name = '&name';
Enter value for name: siva

NAME
------
sql

SQL> /
Enter value for name: raja

NAME
------
odi

SQL> /
Enter value for name: sql

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: 3,651●11 gold badge●77 silver badges●1616 bronze badges
1
Thanks for prompt response. But it is not only 5 rows, it contains around 100 rows. I am working in a project so I cannot give business records here. So I gave sample table with records. Union will not work for 100 records, and for @vBoka's answer id is not a number here. It is varchar and we shouldn't type cast. Only solution is to use lead function!

Comment: As I've already said: Part with UNION ALL represents your sample data. You wouldn't type that, data is already stored in your table which I don't have so I used a CTE (common table expression). You'd use code from line #11 onward. Apart from that, I don't see anything "wrong" about my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use sub-query :

```
SELECT Next_NAME 
FROM (SELECT NAME, LEAD(NAME, 3) OVER (ORDER by id) AS Next_NAME 
      FROM TEST_TABLE
     ) t
WHERE NAME = 'SIVA';
```

Comment: I can not delete my answer because it is accepted (did not know that...). This is the one that should be accepted. Vote up. The only problem that can be is that the id is varchar.